# How to get sum of elements using Java 8 lambda and Steam API

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

How below can be converted into Stream API and lambda expression.

```
double journalSize = 0;
List<PersistenceAdapter> allKahadb = ((MultiKahaDBPersistenceAdapter)persistenceAdapter).getAdapters();



for (PersistenceAdapter persistenceAdapter : allKahadb) {
    Journal journal = ((KahaDBPersistenceAdapter) persistenceAdapter).getStore().getJournal();
    int noOfJournels = journal.getFiles().size();
    long journalMaxSize = journal.getMaxFileLength();
    journalSize += (journalMaxSize * noOfJournels)/ Memory.ONE_MB;
}
```

I tried doing with map and sum of stream but nothing helped? Basically i need sum of journal size.

Answer (score 1):

`map` your objects to `Journal` instances and then map them to the `double` values you wish to sum:

```
double journalSize =
    allKahadb.stream()
             .map(pa -> ((KahaDBPersistenceAdapter)pa).getStore().getJournal())
             .mapToDouble(j -> ((double) j.getMaxFileLength() * j.getFiles().size()) / Memory.ONE_MB)
             .sum();
```

Comment: Thanks Eran for help, How to handle exception inside map(()-> ), actually  ((KahaDBPersistenceAdapter)pa).getStore().getJournal()) throws IO exception.
Putting entire snippet in try catch is not working out.
I just started working with Stream, try to find way with Stream